# what does "that" refer to

Tags: meaning-in-context, relative-pronouns

What does the 2nd "that" refer to in this following passage?

> The story of Cabeza De Vaca and his companions has its origins in the Caribbean archipelago, that immense arch of green gems set against a turquoise sea **that** was Spain's first foothold in America.

Answer (score 1):

It is referring to "the Caribbean archipelago".

In this sentence, "that" is used with definition 4 from [here](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/that?s=t):

> 4. (used as the subject or object of a relative clause, especially one defining or restricting the antecedent, sometimes replaceable by *who*, *whom*, or *which*):
>
> *the horse that he bought.*

In this case, it could be replaced with "which" :

> that immense arch of green gems set against a turquoise sea**, which** was Spain's first foothold in America.

If you're curious, here is a discussion about [That vs. Which](https://www.dictionary.com/e/that-vs-which/).

Comment: I might be inclined to say the *first* "that" (not highlighted by OP) refers back to "the Caribbean archipelago", whereas the *second* one refers back to immediately-preceding "immense arch of green gems". But semantically they both refer to the same thing anyway, so it doesn't really make any difference.